# Macro to color Summary Tasks is 90% working, cannot figure out why it is not 100% working

Tags: vba, ms-project

The below code works only if all Summary Tasks are completely expanded.  If any of the Summary Tasks are collapsed the codes faults.

I do not know what to even try in order to fix this issue.

```
 Sub ColorSummaryTasks()
 Dim t As Task
 Dim i As Integer

 i = 1
 For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

     If t.Summary Then

         SelectRow row:=i, rowrelative:=False

         Select Case t.OutlineLevel
             Case 1
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&H1099FF   'Hex code needs to be reversed
             Case 2
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFF9900
             Case 3
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&H66FF66
             Case 4
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&H10CC99
             Case 5
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&HDD3377
             Case 6
             Font32Ex CellColor:=&HFF00FF

         End Select

     End If

 i = i + 1
 Next t
 End Sub
```

The expected result is for the code to work whether the Summary Tasks are expanded or not.  What is happening is if there are 3 collapsed rows under a Summary Task it will not color the next 3 un-collapsed rows whether they are Summary Tasks or not.  The Imgur link shows what happens when the macros is ran with the Summary Tasks both collapsed and open.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuP6G.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that the code is looping through tasks in two different ways. Looping through the [task collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.tasks(object)) will go through ***every task*** whether visible or not. Using the [SelectRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.selectrow) method works on ***visible tasks only***.

The simplest way to get these two methods in sync is to start by showing all tasks. Put this code before your loop*:

```
FilterApply "All Tasks"
SelectAll
OutlineShowAllTasks
SelectBeginning
```

* Note that this presumes a task view is active and that Group By is set to [No Group].

Alternatively, you can select the desired task by using the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method rather than using SelectRow.  FYI: This will skip summary tasks that are not visible.

```
Sub ColorSummaryTasks()
 Dim t As Task

 For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

     If t.Summary Then

         Find Field:="Unique ID", Test:="equals", Value:=t.UniqueID
         If ActiveCell.Task.UniqueID = t.UniqueID Then

             Select Case t.OutlineLevel
                 ' code here
             End Select

        End If

     End If

 Next t
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you @Rachel.  I went with the second option as I do not want the schedule to automatically expand in the first option.  Also, my end goal is for this macro to run automatically when a Summary Task is created.